# Android Constrain Layout use too many memory (ram) (memory leak)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I really dont understand what happen on constrain layout.

My old ui use only 15 MB of ram while the new ui use ~400MB

Anyone has an idea?

Old ui

Use ~15MB of ram on an actual Android device
[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text=" 11 January 2016"
    android:id="@+id/dateTv"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="12 : 59 PM"
    android:id="@+id/timeTv"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/dateTv"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/dateTv"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/seekBarFoodQuantity"
    android:max="10"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/decrease"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeTv"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/increase"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

<TextView
    android:text="-"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="49dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:id="@+id/decrease"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:background="@color/red_300"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/seekBarFoodQuantity"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBarFoodQuantity" />

<TextView
    android:text="+"
    android:layout_width="49dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:id="@+id/increase"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:background="@color/green_400"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/seekBarFoodQuantity"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBarFoodQuantity" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/quantity"
    android:layout_width="137dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvQuantity"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBarFoodQuantity"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:text="Save"
    android:layout_width="137dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvSave"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBarFoodQuantity"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

<include layout="@layout/bottom_bar" android:id="@+id/bottombarAddFood"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout4" />
```

New ui

Use ram on an actual Android device more than 400 MB!!!
[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text=" 11 January 2016"
    android:id="@+id/dateTv"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="12 : 59 PM"
    android:id="@+id/timeTv"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/dateTv"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/dateTv" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBarFoodQuantity"
    android:max="10"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/decrease"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/decrease"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/increase"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/decrease" />

<TextView
    android:text="-"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="49dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:id="@+id/decrease"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:background="@color/red_300"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="+"
    android:layout_width="49dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:id="@+id/increase"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:background="@color/green_400"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/seekBarFoodQuantity"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBarFoodQuantity" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/quantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvQuantity"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/seekBarFoodQuantity"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBarFoodQuantity"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/seekBarFoodQuantity" />

<TextView
    android:text="Save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvSave"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottombarAddFood"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

<include layout="@layout/bottom_bar" android:id="@+id/bottombarAddFood"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout4" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioLittle"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dateTv"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/radioMedium"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.33" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioMedium"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/radioMost"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/radioMost"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.75"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioMost"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/radioLittle"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/radioLittle"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/radioMedium"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/radioLittle" />

<TextView
    android:text="Little"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/radioLittle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioLittle"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/radioLittle" />

<TextView
    android:text="Medium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/radioMost"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioMost"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/radioMost" />

<TextView
    android:text="Most"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/radioMedium"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioMedium"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/radioMedium" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that the bug is on the 
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'

The new ui use alpha4 but old ui use alpha3

Then I use

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha3'
```

with the new ui.
**Now the bug has been fixed on the alpha7 too**

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in alpha 4 that got resolved in alpha 6 that might explain what you are seeing (this is clearly completely abnormal, Constraint Layout actually should use very little ram). Could you check if that fixes your issue, and if not file a bug? Thanks!

Comment: The other answer already stated that it was fixed by downgrading to alpha3

Comment: Sure, but alpha 3 is not recommended to use :-) -- there is a reason we released alpha 4, alpha 5 and alpha 6... (Many bug fixes, performance improvement, and API changes). Specifically alpha 4 had a big internal overall helping with performance, so knowing that alpha 3 doesn't have the problem is great, but it would be a lot more useful to know if alpha 6 fixes the issue -- it likely will, but if not that's something we need to take care of)